# Support for "sub-organization" or non-global organization namespacing

Tags: azure-devops

We are looking at adopting Azure DevOps' hosted and cloud-based solution.  However, organization names appear to be global in namespacing.  Therefore, private internal project organization names become exposed to enumeration attacks and make it difficult for us to organize our projects.

A very simple example would be that we have an internal organization called Finance.  Since it's global namespacing, we would have to call it Acme-Finance.  Then we'd have to have Acme-Infrastructure, Acme-ProjectX, Acme-Project-Y.  That is very messy.

Gitlab, as an example, has an infinite set of sub-organizations that you can create.

We could solve this with the on-premises version and using Collections, but it would lag behind all of the updates and functionality in the cloud version.

Comment: I think this is more like a feature request.Could you please make a request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21)